# How to re-organize partition sizes on a Software RAID on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, diskmanagement, ubuntu-22.04

I have an existing **Software RAID** consisting of 4 partitions on a Server running Ubuntu 22. I want to **decrease** the size of the md2 partition and **increase** the size of the md3 partition.

How do achieve that without data loss? The partition to be decreased in size has sufficient space to do so.

```
root@Ubuntu-2204-jammy-arm64-base ~ # cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid10]
md3 : active raid6 nvme0n1p5[0] nvme1n1p5[1] nvme2n1p5[2] nvme3n1p5[3]
      5378365440 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      [==========>..........]  resync = 50.1% (1347715200/2689182720) finish=105.4min speed=212018K/sec
      bitmap: 21/21 pages [84KB], 65536KB chunk

md2 : active raid6 nvme2n1p4[2] nvme0n1p4[0] nvme1n1p4[1] nvme3n1p4[3]
      2111567872 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
        resync=DELAYED
      bitmap: 8/8 pages [32KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 nvme0n1p2[0] nvme3n1p2[3] nvme1n1p2[1] nvme2n1p2[2]
      4189184 blocks super 1.2 [4/4] [UUUU]

md1 : active raid1 nvme1n1p3[1] nvme0n1p3[0] nvme2n1p3[2] nvme3n1p3[3]
      1046528 blocks super 1.2 [4/4] [UUUU]
```

Disk sizes:

```
root@Ubuntu-2204-jammy-arm64-base ~ # df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            26G  2.4M   26G   1% /run
/dev/md2        2.0T  2.1G  1.9T   1% /
tmpfs           126G     0  126G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/md1        989M  129M  810M  14% /boot
/dev/nvme3n1p1  256M  340K  256M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/md3        5.0T   25G  4.7T   1% /home
tmpfs            26G     0   26G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs            26G     0   26G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is quite complex. I suggest a careful reading of `mdadm` manpage (especially the "Size Changes" and "RAID-Devices Changes" sections) before doing anything.

***If unsure, seek for professional help.***

To accomplish what you want, you need to:

- shrink the filesystem on top of `md2` (xfs can not be shrunk so, if you are using it, then stop now)
- shrink the array with `mdadm --grow`
- reduce the backing partitions (`p4`)
- use `partprobe` to notify the kernel about the change
- now, enlarge the partitions (`p5`) backing `md3`
- re-run `partprobe`
- grow the array with `mdadm --grow`
- expand the filesystem

As you can see, there are many steps to follow. Any errors and your data are lost.

*Again, if unsure, seek for qualified help.*

Comment: Thank you. I now understand the principles of what needs to be done, which helped me a lot. However, I will give this in professional hands.